# Selecting parts of algebraic expressions?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

```
 (a1 q1^2 + b1 p1^2 + c1 q1 + d1 p1 + e1) E^(a2 q1^2 + b2 p1^2 + c2 q1 + d2 p1 + e2)
```

Is there a command to select factor polynomial

```
(a1 q1^2 + b1 p1^2 + +c1 q1 + d1 p1 + e1)
```

and exponent of `E`

```
(a2 q1^2 + b2 p1^2 + c2 q1 + d2 p1 + e2)
```

from the top expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
myEq = (a1 q1^2 + b1 p1^2 + +c1 q1 + d1 p1 + e1) 
        E^(a2 q1^2 + b2 p1^2 + c2 q1 + d2 p1 + e2);

myEq /. a_ E^b_ -> a
```

and

```
myEq /. a_ E^b_ -> b
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Exponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exponent.html) and [`Coefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Coefficient.html) as follows:

```
exp = (a1 q1^2 + b1 p1^2 + c1 q1 + d1 p1 + e1) E^(a2 q1^2 + b2 p1^2 + c2 q1 + d2 p1 + e2);

Exponent[exp, E]
```

> e2 + d2 p1 + b2 p1^2 + c2 q1 + a2 q1^2

```
Coefficient[exp,  E, Exponent[exp, E]]
```

> e1 + d1 p1 + b1 p1^2 + c1 q1 + a1 q1^2

Answer (score 2):

Another way. It works because both of the sub-expressions to be extracted have head `Plus` and are the only ones to do so.

```
expr = 
  (a1 q1^2 + b1 p1^2 + c1 q1 + d1 p1 + e1) 
    E^(a2 q1^2 + b2 p1^2 + c2 q1 + d2 p1 + e2);
{expon, factr} = Extract[expr, Delete[-1] /@ Position[expr, Plus]];
```

```
factr
```

> ```
> e1 + d1 p1 + b1 p1^2 + c1 q1 + a1 q1^2
> ```

```
expon
```

> ```
> e2 + d2 p1 + b2 p1^2 + c2 q1 + a2 q1^2
> ```